# How to send events from file to event hub

Tags: python, events, performance-testing, message, azure-eventhub

I am new to EventHub and using Python scripts to send events one by one to Eventhub in my project. Is it possible to keep all the events in a file and send all of them together to EventHub?

What I am trying to achieve is that: Sending thousands of events to EventHub per second. So I can keep all the thousand events/messages in one file and send them in single go.

Please suggest ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which you can use to send events in batch

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
An example to show batch sending events to an Event Hub.
"""

# pylint: disable=C0111

import sys
import logging
import datetime
import time
import os

from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Sender, EventData

import examples
logger = examples.get_logger(logging.INFO)

# Address can be in either of these formats:
# "amqps://<URL-encoded-SAS-policy>:<URL-encoded-SAS-key>@<mynamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/myeventhub"
# "amqps://<mynamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/myeventhub"
ADDRESS = os.environ.get('EVENT_HUB_ADDRESS')

# SAS policy and key are not required if they are encoded in the URL
USER = os.environ.get('EVENT_HUB_SAS_POLICY')
KEY = os.environ.get('EVENT_HUB_SAS_KEY')


def data_generator():
    for i in range(1500):
        logger.info("Yielding message {}".format(i))
        yield b"Hello world"


try:
    if not ADDRESS:
        raise ValueError("No EventHubs URL supplied.")

    client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)
    sender = client.add_sender(partition="1")
    client.run()
    try:
        start_time = time.time()
        data = EventData(batch=data_generator())
        sender.send(data)
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        end_time = time.time()
        client.stop()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        logger.info("Runtime: {} seconds".format(run_time))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Glat to know it worked for you. Please mark it as an answer  it will help others too.

Comment: Thanks for this approach @MohitVerma-MSFT But how to send "body" & "properties" of message in Batch Mode?
I have configured events like below:

`
data = EventData(body='{"LocationId":123,"UserId":'u.123') data.application_properties = {"Type": "iPhone"}
yield bytes(data)
`

As batch is expecting only bytes and we cannot convert 'EventData' object to bytes it fails, Also the "application_properties" are not getting sent in message.
Can you suggest how i fix this.

Comment: Will check and get back.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version (5.2.0) of the library ([GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub), [Reference docs](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-eventhub/latest/azure.eventhub.html), you could send events by batches and set the body and properties like this:

```
from azure.eventhub import EventHubProducerClient, EventHubConsumerClient, EventData
import json

connection_str = '<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>'
eventhub_name = '<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>'
client = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(connection_str, eventhub_name=eventhub_name)

event_data_batch = client.create_batch()
can_add = True
while can_add:
    try:
        content = json.dumps({"LocationId": "123", "userId": "123"})
        event_data = EventData(body = content) # body can be of type `str` or `bytes`
        event_data.properties = {"Type": "iPhone"}
        event_data_batch.add(event_data)
    except ValueError:
        can_add = False  # EventDataBatch object reaches max_size.

with client:
    client.send_batch(event_data_batch)
```

To consume the events:

```
consumer_group = "$Default"
client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        connection_str, consumer_group, eventhub_name=eventhub_name
    )
def on_event_batch(partition_context, events):
    partition_context.update_checkpoint()
    for e in events:
        print(e.body_as_str())
        print("properties={}".format(e.properties))

with client:
    client.receive_batch(
        on_event_batch=on_event_batch,
        starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
    )
    # receive events from specified partition:
    # client.receive(on_event=on_event, partition_id='0')
```